# Browser page "Not resolved" page hijacked by yandex

Tags: web-browser, dns, browser-hijacking

Any domain that cannot be resolved defaults to yandex right now, on any browser on my system.

Helper objects or extensions are not installed.

It turns out that the ISP (Turk Telekom) is employing DNS Poisening to achive this result. All pages that cannot be resolved now resolve to the yandex landing page.

[image: Yandex Spamming my browser]

Comment: I would guess you missed something in the installation that allowed it to do so.  Programs can be sneaky some times.  Gotta be careful of user agreements.

Comment: "access and change this without a user knowledge" - because you've explicitly installed a program (anti-virus) which is designed to interfere with your access to the net.

Comment: @raz: well I repeated the installation before I wrote that and also checked the TOS agreement, no reference to yandex or the browser at all.

Comment: @symcbean yeah but I would still like to keep my personal preferences

Comment: @HerrK You're absolutely sure it's the AV?  Uninstalling it gets rid of the Yandex change?

Comment: @raz no, I uninstalled it completely now and the problem still persists, I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: Sophos is cleared from this issue, it's turk telekom/TTNET employing DNS Poisening

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the DNS system has been hijacked by yandex in cooperation with turk telekom (TTNET) which in turn results in non resolving pages end up on the yandex landing page.

Answer (score 1):

When the default DNS server of your internet provider doesn't give you the results you expect, you could set a different one in your operating systems network settings.

[Here is a list of IP addresses of public DNS servers](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/a/free-public-dns-servers.htm).

When you need help with setting a DNS server in your operating system, consult the appropriate stackexchange.

Comment: That's already the case right now, but it's still very rude to do this by default with no way to opt out.